# MySQL looking for value fields / value changes?

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way to search for one **or more** "sets" of rows with a certain value.
I hope i'm describing this accurately.

For example, this is my table (displaying a vehicle's speed at a certain time):

```
| timestamp  | speed  |
| 2014-04-01 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-02 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-03 | 0.00   | 
| 2014-04-04 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-05 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-06 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-07 | 20.00  |
| 2014-04-08 | 21.00  |
| 2014-04-09 | 24.00  |
| 2014-04-10 | 22.00  |
| 2014-04-11 | 24.00  |
| 2014-04-12 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-13 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-14 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-15 | 30.00  |
| 2014-04-16 | 34.00  |
| 2014-04-17 | 37.00  |
| 2014-04-18 | 31.00  |
| 2014-04-19 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-20 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-21 | 0.00   |
| 2014-04-22 | 0.00   |
```

Whenever the speed is greater than 0 the vehicle is moving,
so i would like an output like:

```
Tour 1: 2014-04-07 - 2014-04-11
Tour 2: 2014-04-15 - 2014-04-18
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with one query.

First tour you can get in that way

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE speed > 0 ORDER BY timestamp ASC

SELECT * FROM table WHERE speed = 0 AND timestamp > previous_timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Second you can get in that way

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE speed > 0 AND timestamp > previous_timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC

SELECT * FROM table WHERE speed = 0 AND timestamp > previous_timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Each time you should assign to previous_timestamp value found for previous query (using php)

In last tour it is possible it's not finished yet, so if it's no rows in last query you will now it's still on the go.

Of course you should consider cashing tours as I understand after finishing their time won't change anymore.